# how to use the post ID in as a shortcode attribute?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, shortcode

I have created a custom post type in WordPress. I want use the post ID in a shortcode so I can pull specific posts to output the data, which is a Gallery using fields from Advanced Custom Fields.

Here's my function so far:

```
function mbgc_gallery_shortcode( $atts ) {

    // $post_id = $atts['id'];

    extract( shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'id' => '',
        ), $atts )
    );

    $html_out = '123';

    // $post = get_post( $id );

    // if ( $post ) :

        if( have_rows('mbgc_gallery') ):

            $html_out .= '<div class="mbgc-gallery owl-carousel owl-theme">';

            while( have_rows('mbgc_gallery') ): the_row(); 

                // vars
                $image = get_sub_field('mbgc_image');
                $caption = get_sub_field('mbgc_caption');
                $title = get_sub_field('mbgc_title');
                $sub_title = get_sub_field('mbgc_sub_title');

                if ( $image ) :         
                    $html_out .= '<div class="mbgc-gallery-item">';

                        if ( $caption ) : 
                            $html_out .= '<div class="mbgc-slide-caption">';
                                $html_out .= '<h4>' . $caption . '</h4>';
                                $html_out .= '<div class="mbgc-slide-titles">';
                                    $html_out .= '<h6>' . $title . '</h6>';
                                    $html_out .= '<h6>' . $sub_title . '</h6>';
                                $html_out .= '</div>';
                            $html_out .= '</div>';
                        endif;

                        $html_out .= '<div class="mbgc-slide">';
                            $html_out .= '<img src="' . $image['url'] . '" alt="' . $image['alt'] . '" />';
                        $html_out .= '</div>';

                    $html_out .= '</div>';
                endif;

            endwhile;

            $html_out .= '</div>';

        endif;

    // endif;

    return $html_out;

}
add_shortcode('mbgc_gallery', 'mbgc_gallery_shortcode');
```

I'm hoping the shortcode can look like [mbgc_gallery id="401"], as an example. The main thing is I am not sure how to exactly write it in the function to pull the ID.

Comment: Your function seems fine (for pulling out ID), what exactly is not working?

Comment: Nothing is outputting in the front-end. On a random page, I put that shortcode I mentioned in my original post and I only see the `123`, but nothing else. Even a `var_dump` can't return anything for my variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the ID from the shortcode attributes to the ACF `have_rows()` function so that the correct data is retrieved.

```
<?php
function mbgc_gallery_shortcode( $atts ) {

    $attributes = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'id' => null
        ), $atts );

        // $attributes['id'] is now the passed-in ID

        $html_out = '';

        if( have_rows('mbgc_gallery', $attributes['id']) ):

            $html_out .= '<div class="mbgc-gallery owl-carousel owl-theme">';

            while( have_rows('mbgc_gallery', $attributes['id']) ): the_row();

            // vars
            $image = get_sub_field('mbgc_image');
            $caption = get_sub_field('mbgc_caption');
            $title = get_sub_field('mbgc_title');
            $sub_title = get_sub_field('mbgc_sub_title');

            if ( $image ) :
                $html_out .= '<div class="mbgc-gallery-item">';

                if ( $caption ) :
                    $html_out .= '<div class="mbgc-slide-caption">';
                    $html_out .= '<h4>' . $caption . '</h4>';
                    $html_out .= '<div class="mbgc-slide-titles">';
                    $html_out .= '<h6>' . $title . '</h6>';
                    $html_out .= '<h6>' . $sub_title . '</h6>';
                    $html_out .= '</div>';
                    $html_out .= '</div>';
                endif;

                $html_out .= '<div class="mbgc-slide">';
                $html_out .= '<img src="' . $image['url'] . '" alt="' . $image['alt'] . '" />';
                $html_out .= '</div>';

                $html_out .= '</div>';
            endif;

        endwhile;

        $html_out .= '</div>';

    endif;

    return $html_out;

}
add_shortcode('mbgc_gallery', 'mbgc_gallery_shortcode');
```

Use the shortcode like this: [mbgc_gallery id="123"].

Personally I don't like using `extract()` - this turns an array into individual variables, named according to the array element key, and can make debugging difficult. Instead, just access your id like this: `$attributes['id']` as shown above.

Good luck!